# Automatically scroll down as text appears on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing a poem word by word (using lettering.js and jQuery. This is working well. Now I want to add an additional feature: I want the page to scroll down as the text appears on the screen. I am trying:

```
div.lettering('words');
div.find('span').hide();
div.show().find('span').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(delay * i).fadeIn(fadeIn);
    var _this = $(this);
    $('html, body').scrollTop(
        _this.offset().top - $('html, body').offset().top + $('html, body').scrollTop()
    );
});
```

Also tried:

```
div.lettering('words');
div.find('span').hide();
div.show().find('span').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(delay * i).fadeIn(fadeIn);
    var _this = $(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: _this.offset().top
    }; 500);
});
```

But the page scrolls to some position on page load, and that's it. I have the feeling that the _this variable I am using isn't correct.

Any idea how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you setup a simple example on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: My guess would be that `this` isn't referring to the same element as the loop progresses. Try wrapping the code that uses `this` inside of a self-executing anonymous function: http://jsfiddle.net/GfCZh/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are adding content directly to your body and the height of your body gets dynamically changed as the elements get added then you need to do this.

```
div.show().find('span').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(delay * i).fadeIn(fadeIn,function(){
    var _body = $("body");
      _body.animate({
         scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight;
      }; 500);
    });
});
```

What happens in your case is the animation for scrolling down occured immediately which wasnt needed , doing it this way ensures that the slide down animation occurs only when the fade-in animation has completed .

Otherwise if you are not adding content directly to your body you can still do it using the same technique applied to outer and inner.

Answer (score 0):

As @Abhishek pointed out in his answer, I had to use a callback for the scrolling to work properly. However, the scrolling still wasn't working. So I ended up using Abhishek's code combined with the [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin:

```
div.lettering('words');
div.find('span').hide();
$.scrollTo('h3', {duration:500});
div.show().find('span').each(function(i) {
    var _this = $(this);
    $(this).delay(delay * i).fadeIn(fadeIn,function(){
        $.scrollTo(_this, {duration:100} );
    });
});
```

The animation isn't as smooth as I want it to be because `duration: 100` is a bit too quick.. But if I set a higher value, the scrolling will happen after all the text has been displayed, which feels a bit weird.